# How to get row number in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, row-number

I've read many articles regarding how to use a row number in SQLite but none of them gave me the answer I need. I know how to select row number using this query:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT() FROM table WHERE title < t.title OR (title = t.title AND id<t.id)) as rowIndex, t.title FROM table AS t ORDER BY t.title;
```

but if I add `COLLATE NOCASE` (which I need) at the end of the query then the result is completely different.

Comment: How does your query look like without the rownum part?

Comment: It depends on what kind of row number you want: 
If you want a number that uniquely identifies a row in the underlying table(s), use ROWID. 
If you want to number the rows of a query result: Some databases offer a ROWNUM pseuo-field, but sqlite does not AFAIK. A solution using a sub-query has been proposed, for example, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023292/how-to-get-rownum-like-column-in-sqlite-iphone).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query contains an error: the alias "ja" is not defined.

Try it like this:

```
SELECT 
  ( SELECT COUNT(*) + 1 
    FROM "table" 
    WHERE title < t.title OR (title = t.title AND id<t.id)
  ) as rowIndex, 
  t.title 
FROM "table" t 
ORDER BY t.title;
```

However, be aware that this sub-query construction will not scale well. For large datasets you might want to create a temp table and use ROWID instead (as discussed, for example,  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023292/how-to-get-rownum-like-column-in-sqlite-iphone)).

**EDIT:**
Test with COLLATE NOCASE:

```
CREATE TABLE "table" (id INTEGER, title TEXT COLLATE NOCASE);

INSERT INTO "table" VALUES 
(1, "Book A"), 
(2, "Book b"), 
(3, "Book C"), 
(4, "Book B"), 
(5, "Book a");
```

The query yields:

```
1|Book A
2|Book a
3|Book b
4|Book B
5|Book C
```

**EDIT:**

If you do not want to declare the column COLLATE NOCASE, you have to make sure that you use COLLATE in the ORDER BY part as well as in the subquery:

```
SELECT 
  ( SELECT COUNT(*) + 1 
    FROM "table" 
    WHERE title < t.title COLLATE NOCASE OR (title = t.title COLLATE NOCASE  AND id<t.id)
  ) as rowIndex, 
  t.title 
FROM "table" t 
ORDER BY t.title COLLATE NOCASE;
```

Comment: Sorry ja.title was mistake I already corrected it. Your query does work (Same as my) ,but problem is when I edit query "...ORDER BY t.title COLLATE NOCASE;". Do I have to create table using COLLATE NOCASE?

Comment: No, you don't have to do that. However, you have to make sure that you use the COLLATE NOCASE in the sub-query consistently. I have added that to the solution, too.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM main AS t2 
WHERE t2.col1 < t1.col1) + 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM main AS t3 
WHERE t3.col1 = t1.col1 AND t3.col1 < t1.col1) 
AS rowNum, * FROM 
Table_name t1 WHERE rowNum=0 ORDER 
BY t1.col1 ASC
```