# Find place number in queue, peewee producing an illegal sqlite3 query

Tags: python, sqlite, peewee, row-number

I'm trying to find the place number of a ticket in a queue. The query fails at sqlite3, and the error given is quite peculiar: `sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error`. I don't seem to understand how the column references are used.

I've tried separating into more subqueries, looked at countless examples of aggregate use, window functions, etc. in peewee, sqlite and MySQL. What I haven't found is an example of `fn.ROW_NUMBER` in peewee. I checked the query on multiple websites, and they would parrot the same error.

Query generated by peewee:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY "t1"."ordinal") AS ordinal_index 
FROM "dbticket" AS t1 
WHERE (((("t1"."called_at" IS ?) AND ("t1"."abandoned_at" IS ?)) AND ("t1"."removed_at" IS ?)) AND ("ticket_id" = ?))
```

Parameters:

```
[None, None, None, 'red-shibe'
```

The code responsible for this hell:

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
THIS_FOLDER = Path(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
db_file = THIS_FOLDER / 'queue.db'
sqlite_db = SqliteDatabase(str(db_file), pragmas=[('journal_mode', 'wal')])



class DBTicket(BaseModel):
    ordinal = PrimaryKeyAutoIncrementField()
    ticket_id = TextField(unique=True)
    queue_name = TextField()

    initiated_at = DateTimeField(default=datetime.utcnow)
    called_at = DateTimeField(null=True)
    abandoned_at = DateTimeField(null=True)
    removed_at = DateTimeField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.ordinal}:{self.ticket_id}'

in_queue_predicate = (DBTicket.called_at.is_null() &
                      DBTicket.abandoned_at.is_null() &
                      DBTicket.removed_at.is_null())

def ticket_place_number(ticket_id):
    queue = DBTicket.select() \
                    .where(in_queue_predicate)
    place_number = queue.select(fn.ROW_NUMBER().over(order_by=[DBTicket.ordinal]).alias('ordinal_index')) \
                        .where(queue.c.ticket_id == ticket_id) \
                        .scalar()
    return place_number
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any immediate issues, other than that you might check your sqlite version. Window functions are a relatively recent addition and you need 3.25.0 or newer.

```
import sqlite3
sqlite3.sqlite_version
```

Comment: My .exe says 3.29.0, whereas the Python console (in Pycharm) says 3.21.0 :\

Comment: This is most likely it, I'll have to investigate further. Thanks.

Comment: It seems there aren't good solutions. I would have to update Python to the latest version 3.7.4 to get sqlite 3.28.0, or use hacks that seem quite inefficient: [exh. 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16847574/how-to-use-row-number-in-sqlite) [exh .2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023292/how-to-get-rownum-like-column-in-sqlite-iphone/19199219#19199219)

Comment: Ended up upgrading Python to 3.7.4.

Comment: That isn't necessary. You can always compile sqlite and install it system-wide, or build a statically-linked sqlite3 driver: http://charlesleifer.com/blog/compiling-sqlite-for-use-with-python-applications/

Comment: I explored that possibility. I don't want to force my collaborators to do the same. Even needing to use the latest version of Python is hard. In the end, to help everything go smoothly, I did the indexOf operation in Python. The amount of data is small enough for this, in exceptional circumstances.